# Laravel Eloquent - where in, pivot table, potentially very large query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, where-in

Imagine a Twitter style scenario where one user can follow another. A user may then see the posts (or Tweets) that users he/she follows have made.

Example database structure:

```
users (id, username, created_at, updated_at)
posts (id, user_id, body, created_at, updated_at)
follows (id, follower_id, followed_id, created_at, updated_at)
```

User model

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'users';

    /* A user can follow another user */
    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'follows', 'follower_id', 'followed_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now, my initial approach using Eloquent would be to do something like:

```
// Within the User model
public function getFeed()
{
    // Ids of all follows
    $ids = $this->follows()->lists('followed_id');

    // Append this user's id
    $ids[] = $this->attributes['id'];

    // Grab up to 20 posts by people with these ids, ordered in descending order by date (Eager loading the user object associated with each post)
    return Post::whereIn('user_id', $ids)->with('user')->latest()->take(20)->get();
}
```

Which will result in the following underlying queries:

```
select `followed_id` from `users` inner join `follows` on `users`.`id` = `follows`.`followed_id` where `follows`.`follower_id` = ?
select * from `posts` where `user_id` in (?, ?) order by `created_at` desc limit 20
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in (?, ?)
```

In this case, I have only 2 user records in my table, who follow each other. What would happen if the user followed 1 thousand, 1 million, 10 million people? The second query would become very long, perhaps too long? Perhaps this approach would cause other issues.

My natural approach to this problem in SQL would be to do one query, something like:

```
SELECT p.body, p.created_at, u.username FROM follows AS f
LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON f.followed_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE f.follower_id = 1
ORDER BY p.created_at DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Is the approach I have taken using eloquent appropriate, and will it be able to cope (not knowing the number of user/follows records there may be in the future)? If not, is there another approach using eloquent that would be better? Would it be better to do everything in one SQL query like I've done above? Any other thoughts/suggestions are appreciated.

I love using Laravel with Eloquent, but I am worried that the way it performs queries under-the-hood, might not always prove to be the best approach. It's pretty clever, but I don't expect it to be able to do everything in the best way.

Comment: In this case you are better off with using `DB::raw` then depending on the relationship query.

Comment: The big query has one fatal flaw: order by and limit has the fatal flaw that in the worst case the database first does the joins, then does the sorting and then it limits that sorting to 20. Meaning if you have a user following 1 million other users you first geht the really huge join and then it does the sorting and then only takes the first 20. To be honest I can't account for possible optimizations that the query optimizer fo mysql does but i don't thik it will be intelligent enough to say only select the most recent 20 lines of each user and then sort that and take the most recent 20 of em

Comment: PDO bindings have limit ~65k so you won't be able to run that big query anyway. I suppose MySQL (relational dbs for that matter) is not the best driver for this kind of stuff. And you have wrong order of the keys in the `followers` relation.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I suppose an upper limit/cap on the number of people a user can follow would remove the risk of attempting to perform a query that is >65k. Would you agree? What would you suggest instead of MySQL? Some kind of NoSQL solution?

Comment: Also @JarekTkaczyk. Are you sure the order of the keys in my follows relationship are incorrect? The queries are yielding the correct results (By fluke maybe). I thought the values of `belongsToMany` were model (User), pivot table name (follows), foreign key (follower_id - i.e. this user is a follower of), other key (followed_id - i.e. the user being followed)

Comment: *1* Yes, a cap would do. Also, it's unlikely to have that many people in the feed for a real user.     *2* A graph db, read this for a starter https://blog.twitter.com/2010/introducing-flockdb     *3* Positive. `belongsToMany` signature is this `(Model, table, current_model_key_on_pivot_table, other_key_on_pivot_table)`

Comment: Thanks again. Cheers for the link, interesting read. However, I still don't see my fault on the relationship. `current_model_key_on_pivot_table` in my case would be `follower_id`, that is, the user that is represented by an instance of this model is the follower, and he/she follows `other_key_on_pivot_table` another user (`followed_id`). Am I missing something, how would you see it?